# how to make a live stream swf radio works on safari

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, jquery-mobile, safari

What is the best way of making a live stream `embed` `SWF Player`  Radio from `http://streamcyclone.com/`  Works on iphone  safari

could not find any help topic on this any where all talks about converting locally and upload to the server

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
 src="http://manage.streamcyclone.com/player/player.swf" width="260" height="80" 
 style="undefined" id="mpl" name="mpl" quality="high" allowfullscreen="true" 
   allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="opaque" flashvars="****************">
```

Comment: use phonegap media library and play them , if you need more explanation i will explain more

Comment: @Ocelot thanks for respond ... and yes please i need more information on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's simple you can use 
https://github.com/devgeeks/phonegap-plugins/tree/AudioStreamer/iPhone/AudioStream

it is a phonegap plugin(official) just for streaming audio files. use it just like what is says in read.me.

Comment: do you know if or if not i can use this with android

Comment: plugins are platfor based you should find another plugin in android